# OAuth Access token not able to fetch in Mule

Tags: mule

I am trying to use google api by implementing Oauth2 in Mule Connector. But there I got error of not able to fetch Oauth access token even though I set right credential..

```
 Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: OAuth access token could not be extracted from: {
  "access_token" : "ya29.GlzxA5CJ8FcIay3YXE7sG2spkYYfkcTei6NW_gunsIPW2kSYJToKh1oOyUwkRoy-p-iuGIwLsi5gKvzhZQPMY9wjPkdxR6YJYVswtR3K3iGXlidqbp1_LAQoEHoX0w",
  "expires_in" : 3599,
  "token_type" : "Bearer"
}
    at org.mule.security.oauth.util.DefaultOAuthResponseParser.extractAccessCode(DefaultOAuthResponseParser.java:36)
    at org.mule.security.oauth.BaseOAuth2Manager.fetchAndExtract(BaseOAuth2Manager.java:586)
    at org.mule.security.oauth.BaseOAuth2Manager.fetchAccessToken(BaseOAuth2Manager.java:432)
    at org.mule.modules.drivecon2.adapters.DriveCon2ConnectorOAuth2Adapter.fetchAccessToken(DriveCon2ConnectorOAuth2Adapter.java:207)
```

Comment: Please try to explain your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making new connector than its a common problem.
Definitely, Access_token is generating but, mule cant access it because of wrong regex. 
It is causing because default regex for accepting

```
accessTokenRegex = "\"access_token\":\"([^&]+?)\"",
```

than please add a space between

**:**

like this,

```
accessTokenRegex = "\"access_token\" : \"([^&]+?)\"",
```

this will solve your problem.